# Android closes on login screen when backspace pressed on login activity

Tags: java, android

the application I am working on has a login page where users put in their credentials, and log in.

For some reason, if the user presses the backspace key while typing the password, the application just closes back to the phone's main screen.

The only logcat result that is shown upon the press is:

```
4332-4332/com.etc.etc W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

I looked around but could not find a fix for this - maybe I am just missing something.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I have found this code which was responsible for this. I don't know what the previous developer had in mind, but after commenting it out there were no more issues.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    finish();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Backspace key of soft keyboard?

Comment: Yes, the back arrow with the x through it, above the next/done buttons.

Comment: Please show more log, specially the red portion.

Comment: The username only returns if you try to do backspace in an empty editText, and password returns it no matter what, even if there are still other values inside it.

Comment: Yup, thank you for the help :) Just curious, any idea what the intention was with this code?

Comment: Well from what I know, onKeyDown() is used to override Back button. But I guess the code was not needed at all! Can't say what the previous developer had in mind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back button, by default, finishes an Activity. If you don't want it to finish, override back press function:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 //Do whatever you want or do nothing
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but I was talking about the backspace key on the keyboard that deletes character by character.

Comment: @tacoman50 Ok thats strange, can you please post whole logcat?

Comment: The only thing that happens as a result of the press in log cat is what I posted up above.

Comment: This login screen is the first activity that appears when the application is run, so I don't know what I would have to close with that code.

Comment: Looking over your suggestions, I feel so silly for not having found  this sooner. The code I found and commented out was:

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
  finish();
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

Comment: @tacoman50 Post as edit to your question. But judging from it, I guess you called finish in onKeyDown().